# Multiselector fields in a Form

Tags: extjs

I have a class that extends Ext.form.Panel and has multiple "xtype:'multiselector'" fields contained in 'items'.

How can I access them by form.getFields() method just like any other field? Tried formBind but it doesn't seem to work. How to access them in a form?

Answer (score 1):

The multiselector component is extended from the Grid Panel, so you cannot use the getFields() to get a reference to it.
What you can do however, is get with:

`var myMultiselectors = formPanel.query('multiselector');`

Notice that I've used formPanel and not form for this, meaning that you are going to use the container and not container.getForm() to make this query.

This should work and give you a reference to your multiselector.